# how to fix tail: read error: Stale file handle

Tags: kubernetes, nfs

Today when I trace the application logs, it shows an error below:

```
│ tail: read error: Stale file handle                                                                                                                                          │
│ tail: read error: Stale file handle                                                                                                                                          │
│ tail: read error: Stale file handle                                                                                                                                          │
│ tail: read error: Stale file handle                                                                                                                                          │
│ tail: read error: Stale file handle                                                                                                                                          │
│ tail: read error: Stale file handle                                                                                                                                          │
│ tail: read error: Stale file handle                                                                                                                                          │
│ tail: read error: Stale file handle                                                                                                                                          │
│ tail: read error: Stale file handle                                                                                                                                          │
│ tail: read error: Stale file handle                                                                                                                                          │
│ tail: read error: Stale file handle                                                                                                                                          │
│ tail: read error: Stale file handle                                                                                                                                          │
│ tail: read error: Stale file handle                                                                                                                                          │
│ tail: read error: Stale file handle                                                                                                                                          │
│ tail: read error: Stale file handle                                                                                                                                          │
│ tail: read error: Stale file handle                                                                                                                                          │
│ tail: read error: Stale file handle                                                                                                                                          │
│ tail: read error: Stale file handle
```

I searched my application and did not find the log entry, seems it did not output this error message from the application. more likely thrown by the NFS file system. Why did this error happen? is it possible to fix this error? the NFS file store and read works fine from the kubernetes pod right now, but this error still outputs from std output. I have searched from the internet, it more likely happens when mount NFS, in my case, the mount look like success, it happens when using the NFS(v4.0). This is my Kubernetes pv manifest file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs-cv-server-pv
status:
  phase: Bound
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 8Gi
  nfs:
    server: 3659b3r32-pl30925.cn-hangzhou.nas.aliyuncs.com
    path: /k8s/reddwarf-pro/cv-server-service
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  claimRef:
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    namespace: reddwarf-pro
    name: cv-server-pv-claim
    uid: 52e87ead-6cad-4456-9095-6e3b601672a1
    apiVersion: v1
    resourceVersion: '126114406'
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  mountOptions:
    - vers=4.0
    - noresvport
  volumeMode: Filesystem
```

The docker base image was alpine `version 3.18`. Yes, the NFS mounted correctly because it works for a month, and I've only been facing the issue recently.

Comment: For which operation are you getting this error?  Did the NFS mount correctly? Can you provide the configuration files or documents you have followed. Try by restarting your application, if you are still facing the issues, unmount and remount the file system.